# Date to numbers word in SageX3 Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, erp, sage-erp

Problem: I tried to create a formula in Crystal reports to convert dates from numerical to text in French (example: 01/01/2002 -> deux mil deux le un janvier) but when I print it in sageX3 it converts to ENG.

This is my code:

```
Local StringVar year_ := ToText(Votre_Date, "yyyy");

Local StringVar day_  := ToText(Votre_Date, "dd");

Local StringVar month_:= MonthName(month(Votre_Date));

ProperCase( ToWords(ToNumber(year_),0) ) + " Le " + ProperCase( ToWords(ToNumber(day_), 0) ) + " " + month_
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes default language from "The Environment Locale settings".
Try changing language for server where SAGE is installed

For windows :  Start->Control Panel-> Region & language